# How to multiply all possible combinations of columns in R and use them into a multiple linear regression model?

Tags: r, regression, combn

Suppose I have three columns in a data frame A, B and C respectively. The number of rows for each column are 10. Now, I want to multiply all possible combinations of the columns by taking 2 at a time. So, the columns that I want are A*B, A*C,B*C. How shall I get this using R. Also, I want to use these columns A*B, A*C, B*C into several iterations of a multiple linear regression as follows: Y ~ A + B + C + A*B/A*C/B*C. The model iterations has to be computed through a for loop.

I have tried this code:

```
cc <- combn(data, 2, FUN = Reduce, f = `*`)
n = choose(ncol(data),2)
model <- list()
for (i in 1:n) {
model[[i]] <- lm(Y ~ A+B+C+cc[,i])
}
```

Now, the problem is cc[,i] is a double containing all the possible combinations of the three columns and it does not have specific name to it. So, in the model summary the interaction variable is named as "cc[,i]" only. I want to change the variable name to either "A*B" or "B*C" or "A*C". How shall I do it?

Comment: `lm(Y ~ .^2, data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this code structure works for you:

```
set.seed(7)
df <- data.frame(A = rexp(10, 1), B = rexp(10, 2), C = rexp(10, 3))
Y <- rnorm(10)
df <- data.frame(cbind(Y, df))

m <- combn(3, 2)

mylist <- list()

for (i in 1:3) {
    new_col <- df[ , m[1, i] + 1] * df[ , m[2, i] + 1]
    df2 <- cbind(df, new_col)
    mylist[[i]] <- lm(Y ~ ., data = df2)
    
}
mylist
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = df2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A            B            C      new_col  
    -1.9290       0.4046       2.0715       0.8587      -0.1156  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = df2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A            B            C      new_col  
   -1.81765      0.33800      1.89724      0.79561      0.03353  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = Y ~ ., data = df2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            A            B            C      new_col  
     -1.402        0.321        1.058       -1.445        5.114
```

Comment: Thank you. But how will I understand which combination of variables the new_col is representing in the model?

Comment: From the m matrix.  Each column represents the column variables that are multiplied to create new_col.  So m col1 = 1, 2 so A * B, col2 = 1,3 so A * C, col3 = 2, 3 so B * C. The indexes are offset by 1 in the for loop to account for Y being column 1 in the df2 dataframe.

Comment: To amplify, the order of the regression outputs in mylist correspond to using AB, AC, BC as the new_col.

Comment: Glad you find it helpful.  Please upvote and check the answer if it provided value to you.  Thanks.